# How to import a csv with a column md5 to mysql

Tags: mysql, csv, md5

I'm trying to import a `.csv` file to `MySql`

This is my `.csv` file:

```
 ,AI,MD5('AIRT2015'),RRHH,14,,,AION S.A. DE C.V.,
```

and this ismy db's structure:

[image]

when I upload the `.csv` file i see password exactly as my `.csv` file...

Any idea about how could I do to upload it encrypted?

Thank you

Comment: Is it possible to remove the MD5()? You can process the rows using LOAD DATA and update the column to be MD5(data) but obviously you'd need to try and strip the actual MD5 bit from the string first.

Answer (score 2):

For a start, there are posts all over the web about why using MD5 alone for storing passwords is not a great idea, (see this [great answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/31846) or search google for more info on this) but to achieve what you want using an md5 hash as an example, you would need to have the password in the `.csv` file without the `md5()` wrapper and to use some kind of scripting language to parse the file and `INSERT` the values into the database. For example, if it is a web application you might use `PHP` along the lines of the following:

```
<?php
// database variables, change these to your details
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbusername = 'username';
$dbpassword = 'password';
$dbname = 'database';
$tablename = '`table`';
// file path
$filepath = 'path/to/file.csv';

// connect to the database
$db = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);

// get the contents of your file as an array of lines
$lines = file($filepath);

// loop through lines in the array
foreach($lines as $line) {
    // split the lines by comma
    $split = explode(',', $line);
    // we know that the password will be the third element in the array...
    // so we hash it and push it back in the same point in the array
    $split[2] = md5($split[2]);
    // build sql query
    $sql = "INSERT INTO {$tablename} (ID_ASOCIADO,USERNAME,PASSWORD,...) VALUES ('" . implode("','", $split) . "')";
    // run query and put result into variable
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    if ($result === TRUE) {
        echo "RECORD CREATED SUCCESSFULLY => " . $line . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo "INSERT FAILED WITH ERROR => " . mysql_error($db);
    }
}
```

for more info on using `php` and `mysqli`, see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.php). They have loads of great examples and explanations, particularly on the dual interface and statements pages.